# Color the mail preview in outlook explorer

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote a simple test macro, which process an incoming mail and search in emailtext for regular expression pattern. 
I want then format the e-mail preview(in Outlook Explorer)in case of match.
But I canot find which is the property to format(to color) the email preview of the current MailItem in outlook explorer. Unfortunately there is also no macro recorder for outlook.

Comment: Preview in the mail item in list or in preview pane? As far as I know, there is nothing like coloring preview with single property. Could you refer to some default Outlook behavior doing this?

Comment: I would say 'Preview in the mail item'. Ona could achieve coloring the preview with outlook conditional formatting, but conditional formating does not support regex.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to color individual items.

But there is a workaround:
You need to be able to finish with setting a field value upon which you are able to build a standard formatting using the Conditional Formatting editor. For example,

1. See [this sample which sets **Replied** field](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-highlight-important-emails-havent-replied-outlook/) according to desired rules.
2. Then a conditional formatting picks up its particular value and gives it a color.

Comment: I know, I thought I could for example edit the mail subject and add/append my text. But what I didn't know ist, that there is not possible to color individual items via vba, because outlook actually does this, with conditional formatting.

Comment: @user615993 – conditional formatting allows mass-coloring (and you can use it as indicated in the answer). But there is no "color" attribute on individual e-mail item you can simply set and achieve desired color directly.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight words in the preview pane, use `Explorer.PreviewPane.WordEditor` property (returns Word's `Document` object). You can then use something like the following:

```
Document.Content.Find.HitHighlight("Test", wdColorYellow, , false, true)
```

Comment: When I try with   Dim doc As Variant and then doc = Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor I get "Runtime Error 424" error. How can I reference the document?

Comment: Sorry, you actually need Explorer.PreviewPane.WordEditor

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error:  "Runtime Error 424".  In the context there is no Explorer-object

Comment: Explorer object is returned from Application.ActiveExplorer